# Does the use of labelled equations and equation references normally slow up rendering?

Tags: support, mathjax

I spent the evening learning how to mark up equations with labels and use references, following the advice [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11491/751). However, this probably took about twice as long as it *ought* to have, because it seems that writing an answer using this feature causes my browser to nearly grind to a halt trying to render the answer (even if I switch to another tab).  I ended up doing most of the editing offline, and then trying to make the necessary adjustments  after pasting in the code.

Is this to be expected? (I'm using Firefox on Linux, in case it matters.)

Are there any "tips" to alleviate this problem?

Comment: When typing a longer answer I almost always type it up in another editor and then copy and paste it into my browser. Also, I do not think I have ever had an issue with `\tag{}`. Not sure about the other commands.

Comment: I use `\tag{}` but not labels or `eqref`; somehow these don't seem to be worth the typing when the post is not extremely long. My impression is that a large number of displayed formulas will slow down the browser, whether they are numbered or not. As Brad does, I type longer answers in a separate editor. Nowadays, it's usually [Caret](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caret/fljalecfjciodhpcledpamjachpmelml?hl=en): lightweight, with syntax highlighting and parentheses matching.

Comment: MathJax in general would apply some measure of slowdown, but it reaching a point to a halt is a bit concerning if you ask me. Might there be any noticeable patterns that tend to trigger more severe slowdowns, or does it seem to happen with just about every configuration?

Comment: Perhaps I should just have used `\tag{}` and manually indicated references.  I suppose resolving equation labels would require considerable processing. (LaTeX would need two runs.) I do find getting the typesetting preview really very nice, so it's a shame to have to edit offline.  But it seems others do it too for longer posts.

Comment: Generally speaking, there shouldn't be any noticeable delay caused by labels and refs. However, IIRC there's a piece of code to prevent label issues in the live preview (preventing duplicate labels etc)' it might be that that part is causing trouble. Do other users experience problems?